# How to check if a particular call is on hold in android?

Tags: android

Is there a way from application point of view to understand that a call from/to a particular number is on hold?

Comment: At the VERY LEAST, show what you know. Dont just ask for the answer, because then you lose the journey to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in the SDK:

[PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

Comment: Hi Jox, the PhoneStateListener does not provide a concrete information if the call is on hold. Even if the call is on hold the state is CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. There is no way to get the detailed state of the call. If you have any information, please let me know.